# how to display text line by line which i enter in edittext on a button click in a layout?

Tags: android

this is my java code. i am trying to display whatever text i enter in edittext.. if i enter a text and click the button it has to be displayed below in a layout.. help me in doing this.

```
private EditText medit_currency;
    private Button mbtn_currencyadd;
private TextView mtv=null;
private LinearLayout mll;
    String s;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
    mtv=new TextView(this);
    medit_currency=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    mbtn_currencyadd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    mbtn_currencyadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               s=medit_currency.getText().toString();
               mtv.setText(s);
               mll.addView(mtv);

        }
    });
}
```

this is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText5"
    android:text="@string/add" />

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

what i have done so far is enough to display a single text entered in edit text. tel me how to do it for multiple text every time i click the button one by one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
    mtv = new TextView(this);
    mll.addView(mtv);
    medit_currency = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    mbtn_currencyadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    mbtn_currencyadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            s = medit_currency.getText().toString();
            s=s + "\n" + mtv.getText().toString();
            mtv.setText(s);

        }
    });
}
```

Your append problem is resolved here...

Here you are adding textview to the layout every time you click on button. This will generate exception. So I removed the exception here too...

Answer (score 1):

Update your `onClick` method as follows:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   s=medit_currency.getText().toString();
   String previousText = "";
   if(mtv.getText() != null) {
        previousText = mtv.getText().toString();
   }
   String newText = previousText + "\n" + s;
   mtv.setText(s);
   mll.addView(mtv);
}
```

*Note: should handle case for* `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you click the button, you're adding the same `TextView` to the layout. You need to create a new `TextView` in your `onClick()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
        mtv = new TextView(this);
        medit_currency = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        mbtn_currencyadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        mbtn_currencyadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   s=medit_currency.getText().toString().trim();
                   s=mtv.getText().toString().trim() + "\n" + s;
                   mtv.setText(s);
                   mll.addView(mtv);

            }
        });
    }
}
```